# Django forms data retrieving and updating problem

Tags: python, django, crud

I've four fields in my models.py file.

```
class Item(models.Model):
product_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
quantity = models.IntegerField()
size_choice = (
    ('S', 'Short'),
    ('M','Medium'),
    ('L','Long')
)
size = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=size_choice,blank=True, null=True)
date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
```

And this is my forms.py file:

```
class ItemForm(ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = Item
    widgets = {'date':DateInput()}
    fields = ['product_name','quantity']
```

As I'm taking two fields only so it will display only two fields in my additem.html file:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <button type="submit">Add</button>
    </form>
```

In my itemlist.html file I can retrieve 'product_name' and 'quantity' from database as it is being saved from additem.html file. But in this itemlist.html file I've created two more inputs for 'size' and 'date'. So from here i want to update data into database(all four coulmns). Updating two fileds is fine but how will i update 'size' and 'field' from itemlist.html file.

```
{% for neww in all %}
    <tr>
      
      <td>{{ neww.product_name }}</td>
      <td>{{ neww.quantity }}</td>
      <td><input type="text" value="{{ neww.size }}"</td> /* This */
      <td><input type="text" value="{{ neww.date }}"</td> /* and this i want to update from here */
      <td><a href="{% url 'update_item' neww.id %}">Edit</a></tr>{% endfor %}
```

My update_item.html file:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Update">
</form>
```

My itemlist views:

```
def itemlist(request):
all_items = Item.objects.all()
return render(request, 'item/itemlist.html',{'all': all_items})
```

And my update_item views:

```
def update_item(request, id):
if request.method == 'POST':
    pi = Item.objects.get(pk=id)
    fm = ItemForm(request.POST, instance=pi)
    if fm.is_valid():
        fm.save()
        return redirect('/itemlist')
else:
    pi = Item.objects.get(pk=id)
    fm = ItemForm(instance=pi)
return render(request, 'item/update_item.html', {'form':fm})
```

I searched on Internet. I didn't find any similar question. I've stuck here since a week. Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First thing to note is that if you are requesting a form data from html template, then it should be under the form tag. and action "PATH TO THE URL containing the views." as following:

```
{% for neww in all %}
    <tr>
      
      <td>{{ neww.product_name }}</td>
      <td>{{ neww.quantity }}</td>
      <form action="PATH TO THE URL" method="POST">
       {% csrf_token %}
      <td><input type="text" value="{{ neww.size }}" name="val1"></td> /* This */
      <td><input type="text" value="{{ neww.date }}" name="val2"></td> /* and this i want to update from here */
      <input type="submit" value="Update">
      </form>
      <td><a href="{% url 'update_item' neww.id %}">Edit</a>
```

and in your views.py file you can request the data to update your tables in the database as following:

```
size = request.POST['val1']
date = request.POST['val2']
```

now you can use these values to be updated in the tables.
There are more options to achieve this functionality in case you want the data prefilled in the form partly using the instances and id. Just check on YouTube or google how to prefill the django form partly. You can also hide the form fields in the html using the css styles.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
def update_item(request, id):
if request.method == 'POST':
    pi = Item.objects.get(pk=id)
    fm = ItemForm(request.POST, instance=pi)
    fm.size = request.POST["size"]
    fm.date = request.POST["date"]
    if fm.is_valid():
        fm.save()
        return redirect('/itemlist')
else:
    pi = Item.objects.get(pk=id)
    fm = ItemForm(instance=pi)
return render(request, 'item/update_item.html', {'form':fm})
```